# Loading contents from webpage in Android

Tags: android

Can any one suggest a solution for the following problems:

1. Is it possible to load contents into my android UI from a web page
2. And secondly i want to play videos in that webpage through the
   android application

Thanks to all in advance

Comment: What kind of contents?

Comment: 1) well yes, but will need some sort of web services
2) not really sure what is question, but you might provide url for some sort of video player.
you should make more clear questions

Comment: Take a look at Sencha touch. It might help u.. you can create WEB based apps

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do these things by using web services. Using ASP.Net or PHP you can write web services  and call them from your android application. You can use Json /Soap for this.

Here are some links. Go through this..

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap
- http://androidexample.com/Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebView to display web page contents, but not all kinds of video can be played. You can not play video from the pages with Flash Player, but the video will be played if the player is HTML5.